# Trouble using isDigit()

Tags: java

I am trying to use isDigit() to verify if a character in a string is not a digit.

```
if (aString.charAt(i).isDigit == false)
```

I am getting the error: cannot invoke isDigit on the primitive type character. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Accidentally posted question before I finished writing it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a static method in the `Character` class, so you need:

```
if (!Character.isDigit(aString.charAt(i)))
```

(Note the use of `!` instead of comparing the result with `false`, btw. Both ways will work, but I view the above as more idiomatic.)